# How to create a linux user group that grants access to USB devices?

Tags: usb, raspbian-buster, permissions

How can I create a new user group that will grant the group members access to USB devices connected to the system?

a.) to all connected USB devices?
b.) only to USB devices with VID=0x1234?
c.) only to USB devices with VID=0x1234 and PID=0xABCD?

The OS version is: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

I have a C++ program that connects to an USB acceleration sensor. The program uses `libusb` and can communicate with the sensor when started with `sudo ./myprogram`. Without `sudo` the program has permission problems.

Comment: You do not normally get permission to everything (unless you are root) which "owns" `/dev` although you can set `suid` on code. Services get permissions - see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75681/8697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `udev` rules to set things like file mode bits and user/group for the devices - so for point c) in your question it's fairly simple - maybe point b) as well, but not point a)

e.g. create file `/etc/udev/rules.d/mydevices.rules` with the content

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="abcd", MODE="0660", GROUP="mygroup"
```

Create group `mygroup` (-r makes it a "system" group)

```
groupadd -r mygroup
```

Then add `mygroup` group to any user that would require access to that device

```
usermod -a -G mygroup someuser
```

I'm not sure if you omit `ATTRS{idProduct}=="abcd"` if it would apply to all products from vendor `1234` - but, you probably don't want that anyway

By the way, there's a group called `plugdev` which is standard in all my pi's and user `pi` is a member of it - I mention this because when adding SDR support, the install creates a udev rules file with rules such as

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f4d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="a803", ENV{ID_SOFTWARE_RADIO}="1", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Comment: I am building my own USB devices based on the Atmega32u4 processor that has built in USB capabilities. All of my devices use the same VID but different PID-s. So in my case it makes sense to allow access to all devices with the same VID using one rule.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works better than you expected. Even version a.) works:

a.) SUBSYSTEMS=="USB", MODE="0660", GROUP="usb"

Comment: well, yeah, I suspected that would happen @mTThomas - but not sure of the side effects! For example, my pi boots from USB :p not sure what udev rules that mess with mode/group would do :p